# ListView SQLite database OnItemLongClick and Dialog

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, onitemlongclicklistener

I have a following problem. I setup database that gets populated with data rows upon creation. I need to have functionality of changing data rows (Dialog). I managed to get Dialog to open upon LongClick but when new entry is added upon button click nothing gets changed. I am not sure where I am wrong.

Here is my file that displays the list:

```
public class Monday extends ListActivity {

    private static final int MyMenu = 0;
    MyDB dba;
    DiaryAdapter myAdapter;

    private class MyDiary {

        public String title;
        public String content;

        public MyDiary(String t, String c) {
            title=t;
            content=c;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        dba = new MyDB(this);
        dba.open();
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_monday);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        myAdapter = new DiaryAdapter(this);
        this.setListAdapter(myAdapter);
    }

    public class DiaryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private ArrayList<MyDiary> fragment_monday;
        public DiaryAdapter(Context context) {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            fragment_monday = new ArrayList<MyDiary>();
            getdata();

            ListView list = getListView();
            list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    new EditListItemDialog(view.getContext(), myAdapter, position).show();
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }

        public void getdata(){
            Cursor c = dba.getdiaries();
            startManagingCursor(c);
            if(c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.TITLE_NAME));
                    String content = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.CONTENT_NAME));

                    MyDiary temp = new MyDiary(title,content);
                    fragment_monday.add(temp);
                } while(c.moveToNext());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragment_monday.size();
        }

        public MyDiary getItem(int i) {
            return fragment_monday.get(i);
        }

        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
            final ViewHolder holder;

            View v = arg1;
            if ((v == null) || (v.getTag() == null)) {
                v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.diaryrow,  null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.mTitle = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.name);
                v.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
            }

            holder.mdiary = getItem(arg0);
            holder.mTitle.setText(holder.mdiary.title);
            v.setTag(holder);

            return v;
        }

        public class ViewHolder {
            MyDiary mdiary;
            TextView mTitle;
        }
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Edit button */
    public void visitDiary(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Diary.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the back button */
    public void visitSchedule(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayScheduleScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Here is a file of Dialog:

```
class EditListItemDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {

    private View editText;
    private DiaryAdapter adapter;

    //  public EditListItemDialog(Context context, List<String> fragment_monday) {        //first constructor
    //      super(context);
    //      this.fragment_monday = fragment_monday;
    //  }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_text_dialog);//here is your xml with EditText and 'Ok' and 'Cancel' buttons
        View btnOk = findViewById(R.id.button_ok);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
        btnOk.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    private List<String> fragment_monday;

    public EditListItemDialog(Context context, DiaryAdapter adapter, int position) {
        super(context);
        this.fragment_monday = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.adapter = adapter;
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //Position is the number of the item clicked
        //You can use your adapter to modify the item
        adapter.getItem(position); //Will return the clicked item
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        fragment_monday.add(((TextView) v).getText().toString());//here is your updated(or not updated) text
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        dismiss();
    }
}
```

If anybody has an idea what might be wrong here(why data rows are not getting updated) I will be very thankful for any help.

logcat while using dialog to update row in the list:

```
04-21 19:18:45.209: I/InputReader(190): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 0
04-21 19:18:45.209: I/InputDispatcher(190): Delivering touch to current input target
04-21 19:18:45.359: I/InputReader(190): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 1
04-21 19:18:45.359: I/InputDispatcher(190): Delivering touch to current input target
04-21 19:18:45.369: V/onEvaluateInputViewShown()(263):  in inputmethodservice value = 1
04-21 19:18:45.369: V/onEvaluateInputViewShown()(263):  in inputmethodservice value = 1
04-21 19:18:45.369: I/DHWR(263): [I] ./../engine/rel/source/wrapper/dhwr_main.c(501) DHWRSetAttribute: SetAttribute
04-21 19:18:45.399: I/DHWR(263): [I] ./../engine/rel/source/wrapper/dhwr_main.c(509) DHWRSetAttribute: ptype: 0, pMode:0x20fb78, nMode:1, pCands:10
04-21 19:18:45.399: I/DHWR(263): [I] ./../engine/rel/source/wrapper/dhwr_main.c(512) DHWRSetAttribute: pMode[0] lang:0, type:0xc
04-21 19:18:45.399: I/DHWR(263): [I] ./../engine/rel/source/wrapper/dhwr_main.c(501) DHWRSetAttribute: SetAttribute
04-21 19:18:45.419: I/DHWR(263): [I] ./../engine/rel/source/wrapper/dhwr_main.c(509) DHWRSetAttribute: ptype: 0, pMode:0x20fb78, nMode:1, pCands:10
04-21 19:18:45.419: I/DHWR(263): [I] ./../engine/rel/source/wrapper/dhwr_main.c(512) DHWRSetAttribute: pMode[0] lang:0, type:0xc
04-21 19:18:45.419: I/DHWR(263): [I] ./../engine/rel/source/wrapper/dhwr_main.c(1294) DHWRSetWritingArea: left:0, top:0, right:0, bottom:0, sizeRate:60
04-21 19:18:46.749: I/InputReader(190): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 0
04-21 19:18:46.749: I/InputDispatcher(190): Delivering touch to current input target
04-21 19:18:46.759: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): startOutput() output 1, stream 1, session 8608
04-21 19:18:46.759: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): getDeviceForStrategy() from cache strategy 0, device 2
04-21 19:18:46.759: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): getNewDevice() selected device 2
04-21 19:18:46.759: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): setOutputDevice() output 1 device 2 delayMs 0
04-21 19:18:46.759: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): setOutputDevice() setting same device 2 or null device for output 1
04-21 19:18:46.759: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): releaseOutput() 1
04-21 19:18:46.769: V/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(95): open driver
04-21 19:18:46.769: V/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(95): get config
04-21 19:18:46.769: V/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(95): set config
04-21 19:18:46.769: V/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(95): buffer_size: 4800
04-21 19:18:46.769: V/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(95): buffer_count: 2
04-21 19:18:46.769: V/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(95): channel_count: 2
04-21 19:18:46.769: V/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(95): sample_rate: 44100
04-21 19:18:46.769: V/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(95): count : 4800
04-21 19:18:46.849: I/InputReader(190): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 1
04-21 19:18:46.849: I/InputDispatcher(190): Delivering touch to current input target
04-21 19:18:46.939: W/AudioFlinger(95): write blocked for 165 msecs, 1984 delayed writes, thread 0xcce8
04-21 19:18:46.969: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): stopOutput() output 1, stream 1, session 8608
04-21 19:18:46.969: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): getNewDevice() selected device 0
04-21 19:18:46.969: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): setOutputDevice() output 1 device 0 delayMs 150
04-21 19:18:46.969: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): setOutputDevice() setting same device 0 or null device for output 1
04-21 19:18:47.039: I/InputReader(190): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 0
04-21 19:18:47.039: I/InputDispatcher(190): Delivering touch to current input target
04-21 19:18:47.069: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): startOutput() output 1, stream 1, session 8609
04-21 19:18:47.069: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): getDeviceForStrategy() from cache strategy 0, device 2
04-21 19:18:47.069: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): getNewDevice() selected device 2
04-21 19:18:47.069: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): setOutputDevice() output 1 device 2 delayMs 0
04-21 19:18:47.069: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): setOutputDevice() setting same device 2 or null device for output 1
04-21 19:18:47.069: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): releaseOutput() 1
04-21 19:18:47.159: I/InputReader(190): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 1
04-21 19:18:47.159: I/InputDispatcher(190): Delivering touch to current input target
04-21 19:18:47.159: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): stopOutput() output 1, stream 1, session 8609
04-21 19:18:47.159: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): getNewDevice() selected device 0
04-21 19:18:47.159: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): setOutputDevice() output 1 device 0 delayMs 150
04-21 19:18:47.159: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): setOutputDevice() setting same device 0 or null device for output 1
04-21 19:18:47.329: I/InputReader(190): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 0
04-21 19:18:47.329: I/InputDispatcher(190): Delivering touch to current input target
04-21 19:18:47.329: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): startOutput() output 1, stream 1, session 8610
04-21 19:18:47.329: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): getDeviceForStrategy() from cache strategy 0, device 2
04-21 19:18:47.329: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): getNewDevice() selected device 2
04-21 19:18:47.329: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): setOutputDevice() output 1 device 2 delayMs 0
04-21 19:18:47.329: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): setOutputDevice() setting same device 2 or null device for output 1
04-21 19:18:47.329: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): releaseOutput() 1
04-21 19:18:47.409: I/InputReader(190): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 1
04-21 19:18:47.409: I/InputDispatcher(190): Delivering touch to current input target
04-21 19:18:47.439: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): stopOutput() output 1, stream 1, session 8610
04-21 19:18:47.439: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): getNewDevice() selected device 0
04-21 19:18:47.439: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): setOutputDevice() output 1 device 0 delayMs 150
04-21 19:18:47.439: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): setOutputDevice() setting same device 0 or null device for output 1
04-21 19:18:47.589: I/InputReader(190): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 0
04-21 19:18:47.589: I/InputDispatcher(190): Delivering touch to current input target
04-21 19:18:47.599: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): startOutput() output 1, stream 1, session 8611
04-21 19:18:47.599: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): getDeviceForStrategy() from cache strategy 0, device 2
04-21 19:18:47.599: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): getNewDevice() selected device 2
04-21 19:18:47.599: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): setOutputDevice() output 1 device 2 delayMs 0
04-21 19:18:47.599: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): setOutputDevice() setting same device 2 or null device for output 1
04-21 19:18:47.599: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): releaseOutput() 1
04-21 19:18:47.679: I/InputReader(190): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 1
04-21 19:18:47.679: I/InputDispatcher(190): Delivering touch to current input target
04-21 19:18:47.699: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): stopOutput() output 1, stream 1, session 8611
04-21 19:18:47.699: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): getNewDevice() selected device 0
04-21 19:18:47.699: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): setOutputDevice() output 1 device 0 delayMs 150
04-21 19:18:47.699: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): setOutputDevice() setting same device 0 or null device for output 1
04-21 19:18:48.069: W/FastDormancy(270):  before ======= ENTER DORMANCY =======
04-21 19:18:48.099: I/WifiService(190): isShowingAccessPointListDialog():false
04-21 19:18:49.269: I/InputReader(190): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 0
04-21 19:18:49.269: I/InputDispatcher(190): Delivering touch to current input target
04-21 19:18:49.389: I/InputReader(190): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 1
04-21 19:18:49.389: I/InputDispatcher(190): Delivering touch to current input target
04-21 19:18:49.399: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): startOutput() output 1, stream 1, session 8612
04-21 19:18:49.399: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): getDeviceForStrategy() from cache strategy 0, device 2
04-21 19:18:49.399: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): getNewDevice() selected device 2
04-21 19:18:49.399: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): setOutputDevice() output 1 device 2 delayMs 0
04-21 19:18:49.399: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): setOutputDevice() setting same device 2 or null device for output 1
04-21 19:18:49.399: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): releaseOutput() 1
04-21 19:18:49.559: I/DHWR(263): [I] ./../engine/rel/source/wrapper/dhwr_main.c(501) DHWRSetAttribute: SetAttribute
04-21 19:18:49.559: I/DHWR(263): [I] ./../engine/rel/source/wrapper/dhwr_main.c(509) DHWRSetAttribute: ptype: 0, pMode:0x20fb78, nMode:1, pCands:10
04-21 19:18:49.559: I/DHWR(263): [I] ./../engine/rel/source/wrapper/dhwr_main.c(512) DHWRSetAttribute: pMode[0] lang:0, type:0xc
04-21 19:18:49.559: I/DHWR(263): [I] ./../engine/rel/source/wrapper/dhwr_main.c(501) DHWRSetAttribute: SetAttribute
04-21 19:18:49.569: I/DHWR(263): [I] ./../engine/rel/source/wrapper/dhwr_main.c(509) DHWRSetAttribute: ptype: 0, pMode:0x20fb78, nMode:1, pCands:10
04-21 19:18:49.569: I/DHWR(263): [I] ./../engine/rel/source/wrapper/dhwr_main.c(512) DHWRSetAttribute: pMode[0] lang:0, type:0xc
04-21 19:18:49.589: I/DHWR(263): [I] ./../engine/rel/source/wrapper/dhwr_main.c(1294) DHWRSetWritingArea: left:0, top:0, right:0, bottom:0, sizeRate:60
04-21 19:18:49.589: V/onEvaluateInputViewShown()(263):  in inputmethodservice value = 1
04-21 19:18:49.589: V/onEvaluateInputViewShown()(263):  in inputmethodservice value = 1
04-21 19:18:49.739: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): stopOutput() output 1, stream 1, session 8612
04-21 19:18:49.739: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): getNewDevice() selected device 0
04-21 19:18:49.739: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): setOutputDevice() output 1 device 0 delayMs 150
04-21 19:18:49.739: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): setOutputDevice() setting same device 0 or null device for output 1
```

Comment: Can you paste the logcat?

Comment: @MrMins no errors are returned, just nothing is being updated.

Comment: @MrMins I uploaded some logcat, some messages came to the logcat while I was trying to update the row

Comment: The log doesn't say much about the problem. Is very curious see the logcat: V/AudioPolicyManager(95): setOutputDevice() setting same device 2 or null device for output 1.
Try debug the application. The first listener is executed? When the error occurs (line, function)? Did you have some successfully attempt before with the same code?

Comment: @MrMins since the code is as it is now I don't get any errors or crashes. Problem is that when in Dialog I click Ok to confirm changes to the row, window closes but the list does not get updated with new data. It never worked properly before.